# codeigniter email function not working fine while sending multiple emails with an attachments

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, dompdf

here is code for sending emails for multiple with an attachment.the loop was running for 1st time only.so it was sending the mail to 1st person and all the remaining was not getting mails.here is my code.since i'm for working from 2days on it.still i didn't get where i had done a mistake.i hope this is best time to learn from you guys.here is my code.

> ```
> <?php
> foreach ($ids as $key => $value) 
>      {
>                   $where['applicant_id']=$value;
>                   $this->db->trans_start(); 
>                   $this->db->where($where);
>           $result=$this->db->get('applicant');
>           if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
>           {
>           $this->db->trans_rollback();
>           }
>           else
>           {
>           $check++;
>           $array=$result->row_array();
>           $this->db->trans_complete(); $update_data[$key]=array('applicant_id'=>$array['applicant_id'],'status'=>'SHORTLISTED');
>     $subject='Congratualations You Had Short Listed For Singing Competition';
>
>              $array['title']='Admitcard';
>              $data=$array; 
>
>              $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
>              $this->email->from('xxx@gmail.com','xxxcompetations');
>              $this->email->to($array['email']);
>              $this->email->bcc('xxx51@gmail.com');
>              $this->email->subject($subject);
>              $this->email->message($message);
>              $this->pdf->load_view('admitcard',$data);
>              $name=random_string('alnum', 9);
>              $this->pdf->render();
>              $pdf = $this->pdf->output(); //$this->pdf->stream($name.".pdf");
>              file_put_contents("pdf/$name".".pdf", $pdf);
>              $this->email->attach("pdf/$name".".pdf");
>              $this->email->send();
>              $this->email->clear(TRUE);
>              $ecount++;
>           }
>       }  
>
> ?>
> ```

------------------------this is the error i'm getting how to overcome this----------

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMPDF_Exception' with message 'No block-level parent found. Not good.' in /home/mycityon/public_html/navy/application/libraries/dompdf/include/inline_positioner.cls.php:38 Stack trace: #0 /home/mycityon/public_html/navy/application/libraries/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php(546): Inline_Positioner->position() #1 /home/mycityon/public_html/navy/application/libraries/dompdf/include/inline_frame_reflower.cls.php(37): Frame_Decorator->position() #2 /home/mycityon/public_html/navy/application/libraries/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php(556): Inline_Frame_Reflower->reflow(NULL) #3 /home/mycityon/public_html/navy/application/libraries/dompdf/include/page_frame_reflower.cls.php(138): Frame_Decorator->reflow() #4 /home/mycityon/public_html/navy/application/libraries/dompdf/include/frame_decorator.cls.php(556): Page_Frame_Reflower->reflow(NULL) #5 /home/mycityon/public_html/navy/application/libraries/dompdf/include/dompdf.cls.php(817): Frame_Decorator->reflow() #6 /home/mycityon/public_ in /home/mycityon/public_html/navy/application/libraries/dompdf/include/inline_positioner.cls.php on line 38

Comment: What errors do you get? and how do you generate the pdf? Which sort of library do you use to generate the pdf?

Comment: i'm using dompdf library which will convert an html page to pdf document and sending as a attachment in the email.

Comment: It is better to save the attachment (the one that is generated by dompdf) somewhere first, perhaps in a temp folder rather than output it straight forward.

Comment: ya i'm saving the generated pdf in a temp folder which was named as 'pdf'.you can find this line in mycode which was used to save the pdf in pdfs folder <?php file_put_contents("pdf/$name".".pdf", $pdf); ?>

Comment: check `if ($this->email->send()) {
                echo 'Your email was sent.';
            } else {
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't know what exactly the error is, so here's  the generic solution

```
 $this->load->library('email');
 $this->email->from('noreply@example.com', 'Example');
 $this->email->to('to@example.com');
 $this->email->subject('Subject Goes Here');
 $this->email->message('Message goes here');
 $this->email->attach('Path/to/saved/filename.pdf');
 $this->email->send();
```

*to* parameters can accepts arrays as well. So that you can send to multiple recipients at once. If you wish to send each email individually, without concealing the information of other recipients enclose it with foreach loops as such:

```
foreach($emails as $recipient){
     $this->email->from('noreply@example.com', 'Example');
     $this->email->to('to@example.com');
     $this->email->subject('Subject Goes Here');
     $this->email->message('Message goes here');
     $this->email->attach('Path/to/saved/filename.pdf');
     $this->email->send();
}
```

hope this can help.

You might want to retrieve the applicant list as follows:

```
$query = $this->db->get('table_name'); // This will get all rows in your applicant table.
$result = $query->result();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); die(); // Will print all applicants in your table.
```

Then you can process it furthermore from within your foreach loop.

Comment: Even i'm following the same process but it was not working fine.i'm sending a pdf as an attachment which was generated dynamically with the help of dompdf

Comment: When you send the email individually (as shown like my example), what error do you get? Try sending those email without attachment, see if you get the same error.

Comment: without attachment it was working fine.but i have to send attachment with the mail

Comment: ya i had find out my error but i'm not getting how to overcome from that one.after generating pdf @ 1st tym. it was stopping the loop execution.so can u plz help me to overcome this prob

Comment: @user3141441 can you update your post and print any error messages you have? It is quite difficult to come up with a solution without seeing any error message(s).

Comment: Ya guys Finally I got Solution For My Problem.Thanks For Your Suport @jeremy R Irawan

Answer (score 0):

I believe the fix is to re-instantiate dompdf. See the following, [DOMPDF, I cannot create two pdf at time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210986/dompdf-i-cannot-create-two-pdf-at-time)