# Cannot redeclare DOMPDF_autoload()

Tags: php, dompdf

I know this question has been asked before but I have not figured out how it should be resolved. For example this [DOMPDF, I cannot create two pdf at time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20210986/dompdf-i-cannot-create-two-pdf-at-time) tackles with the same topic. I have tried to follow the solution but so far not so good. I have a loop where I want to create two pdf files (two invoices). The case 1 works with only 1 loop, during another loop it hangs (Cannot redeclare DOMPDF_autoload() (previously declared in /vendor/dompdf/include/autoload.inc.php on line 24). The cases 2 and 3, which I have tried to apply from the stackoverflow quastion above, do not work at all (some run time errors, syntax errors which I cannot figure out).

This is my code:

```
$invoices = 2;
$invoice_names = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=$invoices; $i++)
{
$invoice_file_name = 'invoice' .$i. '.pdf';
$invoice_names[] = $invoice_file_name;

require '../vendor/dompdf/include/autoload.inc.php';

// disable DOMPDF's internal autoloader if you are using Composer
define('DOMPDF_ENABLE_AUTOLOAD', false);

// include DOMPDF's default configuration
require_once '../vendor/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php';

$htmlString = '';
ob_start();
// This creates html format of an invoice
include('pdf_laskupohja_vanha.php');
$htmlString .= ob_get_clean();

// Case 1 working for the 1. loop
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($htmlString);
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();

/* Case 2
$view = $dompdf->load->view("viewname", $htmlString, true);
//create a new dompdf instance
$dompdf->pdf = new DOMPDF();
//render and output pdf
$dompdf->pdf->load_html($view);
$dompdf->pdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->pdf->output(array("compress" => 0));
*/

/* Case 3
$dompdf->load->library('pdf');
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->set_base_path(['path']);
//create a new dompdf instance (this is the crucial step)
$dompdf->load_view('viewname', $htmlString); 
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
*/  
file_put_contents('../invoices/' .$invoice_file_name, $output);
}
echo "Invoice(es) OK";
```

Is there a "hidden" way to implement these (case 2 and 3) which are not directly shown? Probably including some modification to the dompdf_config.inc.php or a DOMPDF class. The thing is I do not entirely understand structure of php classes. Probably the main solution is to wipe out the class object of the previous loop and create another one but how? Believe me, I have struggled with this for several days now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking a few questions here so I'll answer the one that's probably affecting you the most, the reuse question.

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1056) with reusing the dompdf object instance. The work around if you need to render only a few separate PDFs is to just `unset` your `$dompdf` variable and re-use it.

```
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html('hello world');
$dompdf->render();
$pdfHello = $dompdf->output();

unset($dompdf);

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html('goodbye world');
$dompdf->render();
$pdfBye = $dompdf->output();
```

---

One other noteworthy problem is that you should only include the dompdf autoloader *once*, not once for each loop. Put the require statement at the top of your file.

```
require '../vendor/dompdf/include/autoload.inc.php';

$invoices = 2;
$invoice_names = array();
for ($i=1; $i<=$invoices; $i++)
{
  // PDF-generating code here (NO dompdf require statement)
}
echo "Invoice(es) OK";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but (not mentioned though) I've tried the both suggeestions already. Did not work.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I tried this for the second time and now it worked! The strange thing I did not get it work at the first time (to place autoload.inc.php outside the loop) ??? Well, it was not the first time I was "blind" of something :-| This drives me grazy... But thanks!

Comment: I often have days like that :/