# .PHP page to PDF using dompdf

Tags: php

i have a .php page with connection to a MySql BD to read some information and then I want to convert it to PDF to print the page.
My question is, may I use DomPdf ? Or it only work for only html code?
Thank you!

Comment: Your php code generates html, right ? Anyway, I don't especially know DomPDF but most libraries allow to render whatever you like, such as the content of a variable.

Comment: Yes it also renders html (with `echo` ) but I also have some `if` and `while` code and some `query` too

Comment: But it hasn't to be DomPDF, u know any other lib that allow to generate pdf from an .php page?

Comment: I've personally used [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) for generating PDFs from urls before, so it might work for you.

Comment: use chrome headless - to convert your page to pdf.

Comment: @David PhantomJS works for html and php code together?

Comment: @lazzy_ms that way the URL and the Page number stays on PDF, and I dont want that..

Comment: @CarlosSantiago wkhtmltopdf is also a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic data like this. change fields in $html dynamically.

```
$html = "<table border='1' width='100%' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th><th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yssyogesh</td>
            <td>yogesh@makitweb.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sonarika</td>
            <td>sonarika@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>vishal</td>
            <td>vishal@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        </table>";

// include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents("file.pdf", $output);
```

Comment: That's actually what i've code haha, but I need to put some php code on the $html var and it give always an error :/

Comment: What is the error ? can you please share, might be i can help you in this regards.

Comment: well, here is a solution for your error [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521775/dompdf-error-no-block-level-parent-found-not-good)

Comment: It may be that, but I don't have the file that they talk about :/