# Dompdf library multiple saperate files save not working

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

Hello everyone I am facing a problem with dompdf in Codeigniter when I am trying to save multiple pdf files in a loop. It saves only one file but I need multiple files to save in the folder separately for each user.

**I tried this**

```
public function export_information(){

    $this->load->library('pdf');
    $export_info_sql = "SELECT * FROM offences_issued";
    $export_info_query = $this->db->query($export_info_sql);
    $export_info_result = $export_info_query->result();

    $query_html = "";
    $counter = 1;
    foreach ($export_info_result as $offence) {         

    $directory_path = FCPATH."offences/".$counter.".pdf";   

    $query_html .= "<table width=100% border=1>";
        $query_html .= "<tr><th>Offence ID</th></tr>";
        $query_html .= "<tr><td>".$offence->issued_id."</td></tr>";
    $query_html .= "</table>";

    $this->pdf->loadHtml($query_html);
    $this->pdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    $this->pdf->render();       
    $output = $this->pdf->output();

        if (!file_exists($directory_path)) {            
            file_put_contents($directory_path, $output);
        }

    $counter++; 

    }       
    // echo $query_html;
    // exit;    

}
```

**It shows this error**

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Dompdf\Exception

Message: No block-level parent found. Not good.

Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\project101\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Positioner\Inline.php

Line Number: 44

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\project101\application\libraries\dompdf\src\FrameDecorator\AbstractFrameDecorator.php
Line: 873
Function: position

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\project101\application\libraries\dompdf\src\FrameReflower\Inline.php
Line: 51
Function: position

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\project101\application\libraries\dompdf\src\FrameDecorator\AbstractFrameDecorator.php
Line: 894
Function: reflow

File: D:\xampp\project101\project101\application\libraries\dompdf\src\FrameReflower\Page.php
Line: 141
Function: reflow

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\project101\application\libraries\dompdf\src\FrameDecorator\AbstractFrameDecorator.php
Line: 894
Function: reflow

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\project101\application\libraries\dompdf\src\Dompdf.php
Line: 842
Function: reflow

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\project101\application\controllers\Portal.php
Line: 45
Function: render

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\project101\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dompdf error "No block-level parent found. Not good."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521775/dompdf-error-no-block-level-parent-found-not-good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This fixed the problem**

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/902#issuecomment-431804432

```
html, body { display: block; }
```